Did Akkadian have dental fricatives?
In Labat's Manuel d'epigraphie akkadienne (page 9), we see this chart of Akkadian and Sumerian phonology:

These "spirantes sourdes interdentales" are presumably voiceless dental fricatives, IPA /θ/ (which Labat transcribes as "þ"). About them, he writes:


Dès les plus anciens textes, certains sons akkadiens n'étaient plus que des survivances, en voie de transformation rapide: þ (> š), ś (> s).
From the oldest texts, certain Akkadian sounds were no more than fossils, in the process of rapid transformation: þ (> š), ś (> s).

I've asked before about Ś, but I've never seen a separate þ proposed for Akkadian; Hasselbach tentatively proposes a dental fricative in Sargonic texts, but von Soden (the originator of the Ś notation) transcribes it as Š…which is shown as a separate sound here.
Has anyone else proposed a separate þ in Akkadian of any period? The six separate sibilants here seem excessive, in my experience, but Labat is a standard reference work, so I imagine he knows what he's talking about.

Five sibilants, surely, including <ś>? /θ/ isn’t generally considered a sibilant, since interdental sibilation isn’t physically possible.

@JanusBahsJacquet in the context of Semitic languages I don't think it's especially unusual to see all the coronal fricatives and affricates grouped together and called "sibilants". As you say, this isn't strictly accurate phonetically, but it's a shorter name for a group that gets referred to pretty ofte

Labat isn't using ś in von Soden's sense, but in the Proto-Semitic sense, as the conventional way of writing some sort of lateral fricative.
The problem with Sargonic writing is that, as a general rule, it doesn't distinguish voiced, voiceless, and emphatic consonants. For example, DA is written for /da/, /ta/, and /ṭa/ alike. However, Hasselbach is clear that "[t]he spelling of these three articulations of Akkadian stops with one sign does not mean that we should assume a merger of voiced, voiceless and emphatic stops in Sargonic Akkadian."
So while Sargonic only distinguished three sibilants in writing, it probably had at least five phonemically: to use Labat's notation, ś~š, þ, and s~z~ṣ were written distinctly, and s, z, and ṣ were probably also distinct (given that they were later written distinctly in Assyrian and Babylonian).
The real problem is ś; Hasselbach claims there is no evidence of a distinction between š and ś in any stage of Akkadian, and Gelb and von Soden agree. I suspect Labat may have been misled by von Soden's notoriously confusing spelling conventions.
EDIT: Von Soden and Röllig 1967: XXI claim that the two could have been distinct, but admit there's no substantial evidence for it. Sommerfeld rejects this due to the aforementioned lack of evidence.
Gelb proposed that Proto-Semitic *ð was also preserved in Sargonic, tentatively transcribing it as ž (i.e. the voiced version of š), but this is unlikely. Words from PS *ð are written with the s~z~ṣ glyphs (i.e. the signs for the affricates) in Sargonic, and if *ð/ž had survived as a distinct phoneme, we would expect it to be written either like š or like þ (given the general disregard for voicing in writing).
